# Serving Drupal 7 with built-in PHP 5.4 server

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, webserver

I am looking to develop a Drupal 7 site using PHP's built-in server. I have successfully run Drupal without clean urls (e.g. *index.php?q=/about/*) but clean urls (e.g. */about/*) normally rely on mod_rewrite or its equivalent. In the docs I see you can run the PHP server with a router file like so:

```
php -S localhost:8000 routing.php
```

What should I put in the routing.php to simulate mod_rewrite?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. But since this is a dev copy of the site, do you really need clean URLs? (I'm assuming it's a dev copy of the site.... you shouldn't be using PHP's built-in server for a live system! -- see http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Yes, only for dev. I deploy with Nginx and PHP-FPM. I also do a WordPress site every now and then and it would have the same problem.

Comment: What's wrong with setting up nginx and php-fpm on your dev site? It should take about five minutes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - that may work too, but that's not the question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - A minimal setup makes it easier to work across computers/virtual machines. Also specifically PHP-FPM doesn't work on Windows last time I checked.

Comment: Your question said nothing about Windows so I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 7):

The task is basically to encode Drupal's .htaccess in PHP for your `router.php` file.

Here's a start:

```
<?php

if (preg_match("/\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
  print "Error\n"; // File type is not allowed
} else
if (preg_match("/(^|\/)\./", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
  return false; // Serve the request as-is
} else
if (file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])) {
  return false;
} else {
  // Feed everything else to Drupal via the "q" GET variable.
  $_GET["q"]=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  include("index.php");
}
```

This should be considered alpha quality.  It represents a 3 minute walk through Drupal 7.14's .htaccess file, skipping anything that needed more than 10 seconds of thought.  :)

It does, however, allow me to launch Drupal's install script, with stylesheets, JS and images loaded as expected, and hit Drupal's pages using Clean URLs.  Note that to *install* Drupal in this environment, I needed [a patch](http://drupal.org/node/1414412#comment-5899380) that may not become part of Drupal 7.

Comment: That looks pretty good. You should submit a patch to have that included in Drupal.

Comment: On normal requests the SCRIPT_NAME is index.php which means the last else statement will never be executed.

Comment: @JasonChrista - yes. if we're processing a request for `index.php?q=admin`, we probably don't want to proceed further. Am I not seeing something?

Comment: I mean the SCRIPT_NAME is populated with `index.php` with requests to URLs like `/about/`.

Comment: Another oddity, the popup admin only shows the front page of the admin but not any of the sub-pages. Going to `/admin/` works perfectly fine though.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution myself and I found one in in the [Drupal 8 issues](https://drupal.org/node/1543858):

This works great for me now in my existing Drupal 7 install(s):

Save this as .htrouter.php (or whatever you wish) and run in your Drupal root dir with:

`php -S localhost:8080 .htrouter.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * The router.php for clean-urls when use PHP 5.4.0 built in webserver.
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 * php -S localhost:8888 .htrouter.php
 *
 */
$url = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
if (file_exists('.' . $url['path'])) {
  // Serve the requested resource as-is.
  return FALSE;
}
// Remove opener slash.
$_GET['q'] = substr($url['path'], 1);
include 'index.php';
```

(snippet built from https://drupal.org/files/router-1543858-3.patch)

Answer (score 3):

You can now more easily launch a server with the command:

`drush runserver`

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. `drush` must be an alias or symlink to `drush.phar` otherwise you get an error about not being able to find a file within the phar.